# Is it possible to inspect Chrome's actual UI (not devtools)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is Chrome's UI actually created in HTML? If so, is it possible to inspect that HTML?

[image]

I'm working on a project that involves mocking browser UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome is not written in html so this is not possible. But it is based on the open source project Chromium so the source code is available to look at http://www.chromium.org/